# Strange sound from an unknown application

Tags: applications, audio, logging

From yesterday my Samsung Galaxy S3 (Android 4.4.2) is playing strange music (midi) from time to time and very often. Sometimes it goes as it comes, with no obvious reason. It looks like an alarm. There is no notification. I checked everything a have remember can cause this. **The only way to stop music intentionally is to open task manager and clear RAM**.

I also have tried to stop services and running applications from Settings -> Application manager, but that didn't seem to make change.

Can I detect somehow which process started this music? Because I can use Android Eclipse, is there any log that can help me to trace origin. In logcat I can see that the music player is running.